# How to remove fading effect from HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have HorizontalScrollView with ListView in it and I want to remove fading effect.
I've tried this

```
 android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
```

and this

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

and

```
android:cacheColorHint="#fff"
```

and

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

and this in my HorizontalScrollView

```
    @Override
    protected float getLeftFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    protected float getRightFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return 0.0f;
    }
```

and I still have white fading effect on my LG.

I know that I can solve this problem setting "Over Scroll Mode" to "never", but I need overscroll in my scrollview.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

no idea if you've solved the problem already. If not, perhaps you can try this

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Answer (score 0):

i never test any HorizontalScrollView on an LG phone, but i'm afraid LG has change the HorizontalScrollView implementation so the fading effect will always be displayed

please remember other manufacturer also implementing this kind of changes, on other widget / popup.

anyway what is your android phone version?

Comment: 4.4.2 
checked program on Nexus S(4.1.2), same problem